# For-Looping through Bookmarks in Python Script tool?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool, for-loop, bookmarks

I'm using this script tool, in ModelBuilder for ArcGIS Pro, to set up a map layout, reference a bookmark, and export the layout as a PDF. This model iterates through Urgent Care centers and its corresponding data one at a time (in alphabetical order by center name). Since my model loops through each Urgent Care center (via the Iterate Field Values), it repeats the same bookmark through every loop/iteration. How do I tell it to go from one bookmark to the other?? (I have about 90 centers, so that means 90 bookmarks also)

Here is my script tool:

```py
import arcpy

#input layer
lyr = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

# input name of layout
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
lyt = p.listLayouts("Layout_King")[0]

# Reposition the scale bar
scaleBar = lyt.listElements("MAPSURROUND_ELEMENT", "Scale Bar")[0]
mf = scaleBar.mapFrame
scaleBar.elementPositionX = mf.elementPositionX + 0.0
scaleBar.elementPositionY = mf.elementPositionY - 0.5

# Reposition the north arrow
northArrow = lyt.listElements("MAPSURROUND_ELEMENT", "North Arrow")[0]
mf = northArrow.mapFrame
northArrow.elementPositionX = mf.elementPositionX + 8.8
northArrow.elementPositionY = mf.elementPositionY + 0.7

# Align the title with the center of the map frame
title = lyt.listElements("TEXT_ELEMENT","Name of Map Text")[0]
mf = lyt.listElements('MAPFRAME_ELEMENT',"Map Frame")[0]
title.elementPositionX = mf.elementPositionX + (mf.elementWidth / 3.7)
title.elementPositionY = mf.elementPositionY + (mf.elementHeight / 0.98)

# Reposition the Legend and fix legend title
legend = lyt.listElements("LEGEND_ELEMENT", "Legend")[0]
legend.title = "Legend"
legend.elementPositionX = mf.elementPositionX + 7.7
legend.elementPositionY = mf.elementPositionY + 7.15

# setting layout to bookmark
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("Current")

# add name of layout
lyt = aprx.listLayouts("Layout_King")[0]
mf = lyt.listElements("MAPFRAME_ELEMENT")[0]

# add name of bookmark
bkmks = mf.map.listBookmarks()
bkmks.sort(key=lambda x: x.name, reverse=True)
for bkmk in bkmks:
  mf.zoomToBookmark(bkmk)
lyt.exportToPDF(r"C:\arcGIS_Shared\Exports" + "\\" + bkmk.name + ".pdf")
```

I have heard that this could be accomplished via a for-loop, but don't know how to write one.

Comment: well, you already are using a for loop: `for bkmk in bkmks:`. Doesn't it work to just indent your final line so that you are exporting to pdf on each iteration of the loop?

Comment: Data driven pages do exactly what you are after. Consider converting bookmarks to polygons and use them . I am using script by @PolyGeo for this purpose, cannot find post though.

Answer (score 5):

you need to add the export function inside the for loop, indent the line

```
for bkmk in bkmks:
    mf.zoomToBookmark(bkmk)
    lyt.exportToPDF(r"C:\arcGIS_Shared\Exports" + "\\" + bkmk.name + ".pdf")
```